# Image does not load as grayscale (skimage)

Tags: python, grayscale, scikit-image, imread

I'm trying to load an image as grayscale as follows:

```
from skimage import data
from skimage.viewer import ImageViewer

img = data.imread('my_image.png', as_gray=True)
```

However, if I check for its shape using `img.shape` it turns out to be a three-dimensional, and not two-dimensional, array. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [scikit-image documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.12.x/api/skimage.data.html#skimage.data.imread), the signature of `data.imread` is as follows:

> ```python
> skimage.data.imread(fname, as_grey=False, plugin=None, flatten=None, **plugin_args)
> ```

Your code does not work properly because the keyword argument `as_grey` is misspelled (you put `as_gray`).

**Sample run**

```python
In [4]: from skimage import data

In [5]: img_3d = data.imread('my_image.png', as_grey=False)

In [6]: img_3d.dtype
Out[6]: dtype('uint8')

In [7]: img_3d.shape
Out[7]: (256L, 640L, 3L)

In [8]: img_2d = data.imread('my_image.png', as_grey=True)

In [9]: img_2d.dtype
Out[9]: dtype('float64')

In [10]: img_2d.shape
Out[10]: (256L, 640L)
```

Comment: Got it! by the way: is using `data.imread()` to be preferred over `rgb2gray()` from the `rgb2gray` package?

Comment: I would have done `img = skimage.io.imread('my_image.png', as_grey=True)` because images that are already in grey-scale format are not converted. If you pass `rgb2gray` an image which is not 3-D or 4-D, you get a ValueError.

Comment: Alert! - UserWarning: `as_grey` has been deprecated in favor of `as_gray`

Comment: Fun fact: Grey is the British way of spelling, while Gray is more commonly used among Americans.